# get text from a text field using actionlisterns

Tags: java, actionlistener, gridbaglayout

This is probably a rather stupid problem but I am playing around with gridbag layouts and I am trying to build a basic login screen that sends the users  information to another class that checks with a mysql DB. but before I do that I have to find a way to listen for my login button being pressed and then get the text from the text fields (this last part is where I am running into problems). I have tried declaring the JTextField outside of the addComponentsToPane method but to no avail.

here is my code so far

also I apologies to any neatness I am new to this site and am not yet knowledgeable enought to format my code correctly.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package GUI;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 *
 * @author TeslaSolari
 */
public class login {

    public void login() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and setup the windows
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Setup the content pane
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        //parts
        JButton login;
        JTextField user;
        JLabel[] label = new JLabel[10];
        JPasswordField pass;
        ActionListener loginB = null;

        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //Cpnstraints
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        // Buttons
        login = new JButton("Login");
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        pane.add(login, c);
        login.addActionListener(new Action());

        // textfields / labels
        label[0] = new JLabel("Username");
        user = new JTextField();
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(label[0], c);
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(user, c);

        label[1] = new JLabel("Password");
        pass = new JPasswordField();
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        pane.add(label[1], c);
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        pane.add(pass, c);


    }

    //Actions

    static class Action implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println(label[]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can find an example of just this using a JOptionPane [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852059/522444).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your solution is right (moving the declarations JTextField declarations outside the method), but you might have missed declaring them as static (according to the rest of your class)

```
private static JTextField user;
private static JPasswordField pass;
```