# How would I use LayoutManager to get a layout like this?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, layout-manager

So, I'm totally new to LayoutManager. I've already read about the existing LayoutManager but don't which the best is to get a Layout like this. The different colorboxes represent JPanels.

[image]

Which one should I use?

Comment: how do you want the panels to behave when the window is resized?

Comment: GridBagLayout should work.

Comment: The window shouldn't be resizable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FormLayout from JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/).

Answer (score 1):

That layout might be achieved using a [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) with two vertical groups and two horizontal groups.

Comment: @kleopatra  During creation of a ['two column layout'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16353404/418556) factory method for groups of labels (column 1) and controls (column 2) I realized why people say GL is designed for IDE (i.e. GUI designer) use.  After a lot of work I got a result that was satisfying, but attempts to tweak that slightly to include a bottom row of buttons was utterly *unsuccessful.*  Having said that. A) My statement is merely a statement of fact.  B)  The OP *might* be using a GUI designer, in which case it would only take a 'few moments' to create using this  J2SE layout.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

1. Red is displayed at its preferred size.
2. Blue is filled horizontally
3. Green is filled vertically
4. Cyan is filled vertically and horizontally.