# How do I use GroupLayout properly to move components/panels?

Tags: java, swing

First off, I apologize for the long post, I just wanted to be clear and show you my issue so it can better be resolved.

I have the following code:

```
    JPanel panelCard = new JPanel();

    String[] cards = {"VISA", "MASTERCARD", "DISCOVER"};

    JComboBox cardType = new JComboBox(cards);

    panelCard.add(cardType);

    GroupLayout layout2 = new GroupLayout(panelCCInfo);

    panelCCInfo.setLayout(layout2);

    layout2.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layout2.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup2 = layout2.createSequentialGroup();

    hGroup2.addGroup(layout2.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(cardName)
            .addComponent(cardNumber)
            .addComponent(expDate));
    hGroup2.addGroup(layout2.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(cardNameField)
            .addComponent(cardNumberField)
            .addComponent(expDateField));
    hGroup2.addGroup(layout2.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(panelCard));
    layout2.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup2);

    GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup2 = layout2.createSequentialGroup();

    vGroup2.addGroup(layout2.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(cardName)
            .addComponent(cardNameField));
    vGroup2.addGroup(layout2.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(cardNumber)
            .addComponent(cardNumberField));
    vGroup2.addGroup(layout2.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(expDate)
            .addComponent(expDateField)
            .addComponent(panelCard));
    layout2.setVerticalGroup(vGroup2);

    panelCheckout.add(panelCCInfo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

And when I run it, it displays this window:
[image]

But I would like to achieve this:
[image]

The problem occurs when I try to add a 3rd vertical group with the panelCard in 
the code:

```
    hGroup2.addGroup(layout2.createParallelGroup().addComponent(panelCard));
```

It would seem that the 2 text field are cut off because of this, but I dont want it cut off.

What can I do to achieve the 2nd picture?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is using another `LayoutManager` an option ? This is for example trivial using a `FormLayout` (from JGoodies). `GroupLayout` is as far as I am concerned only designed for UI builders. Not to hand-code anything in it

Comment: `GroupLayout` was indeed created with UI builders in mind, but my experience is that it is great for hand-coded UIs too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.*;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.*;

public class Mastercard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel lblCardHolder = new JLabel("Card holder");
        JTextField tfCardHolder = new JTextField();
        JLabel lblCardNumber = new JLabel("Card number");
        JTextField tfCardNumber = new JTextField();
        JLabel lblExpirationDate = new JLabel("Expiration date");
        JTextField tfExpirationDate = new JTextField();
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Visa"});

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(lblCardHolder)
                    .addComponent(lblCardNumber)
                    .addComponent(lblExpirationDate))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(tfCardHolder)
                    .addComponent(tfCardNumber)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(tfExpirationDate)
                        .addComponent(combo, DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, PREFERRED_SIZE))));

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblCardHolder)
                    .addComponent(tfCardHolder))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblCardNumber)
                    .addComponent(tfCardNumber))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblExpirationDate)
                    .addComponent(tfExpirationDate)
                    .addComponent(combo)));

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

`GroupLayout` is a powerful constraint-based layout manager. When writing a group layout, you basically just describe whether components (or group of components) should be placed in *sequence* or in *parallel*. This description is done independently for the horizontal and vertical axis.

Horizontally, there are 2 groups in *sequence* : the labels, and the rest. The rest is composed of 3 *parallel* things : 2 textfields, and a *sequence* of `tfExpirationDate` and `combo`. This is, in plain english, what the `layout.setHorizontalGroup(...` describes.

Vertically, there are 3 groups in *sequence* : one composed of a label and a textfield in *parallel*, another composed of a label and a textfield in *parallel*, and yet another composed of a label, a textfield and a combobox in *parallel*. This is what `layout.setVerticalGroup(...` describes.

The nesting of these groups and components is important, this is why I indented everything correctly.

I find this approach of describing constraints quite easy to reason about, using only 2 concepts : sequential groups and parallel groups. Compared to grid-based layouts, it has the advantage that you don't break everything each time you want to add or move a component.

Comment: Swap `f.setSize(1024, 768);` for `f.pack()` for a +1.

Comment: I'd prefer the +1 be for my hard-work on this answer... But I don't mind changing this line :)

Comment: *"hard-work on this answer"* Are you implying you wrote that code by hand?  It looks like it was made with a GUI designer.  ;)

Comment: Yes I wrote the code by hand. I stopped using GUI designer years ago, because they make it hard to evolve a GUI design after it was created. And they get in the way when working with a team. They are still useful for prototyping and for learning, though. I admit that I stole the style of indentation from what Matisse (Netbeans' GUI designer) generates.

Comment: *"Yes I wrote the code by hand."*  (stunned) I could not wrap my head around writing `GroupLayout` if my life depended on it.  Kudos!

Comment: Can I ask if you already tried to? Its Javadoc explains its API very well. Actually, I even *enjoy* writing layouts using this API (and it's the *only* layout I enjoy modifying afterwards). I think it's unfortunate that most people consider that `GroupLayout` is for code generators only. That's why I'm trying to answer every SO question about `GroupLayout` !

Comment: I'm glad you asked. [This is my best attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16353404/418556).  It is a relatively trivial (but useful) two column X N row helper method.  On trying to overload it to also provide for 'a row of buttons, centered at the bottom', I failed dismally.

Comment: *"That's why I'm trying to answer every SO question about GroupLayout !"* I'll be sure to keep an eye out for them.  :)

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure `GroupLayout` is appropriate for generic code like yours. I'll try to answer this one when I have the time. Thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out using a complex combination of GridBagLayout and BorderLayout

what a mess.... :)